# How to check if HTML form validation passed and trigger event

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form with HTML validation for telephone number. I need to be able to validate that the input is valid, and only if its valid, to trigger a mixpanel event. I can validate the input, but having trouble figuring out if the input is validated and triggering the event.

**HTML**

```
<form class=contact method=get action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form">
<input type="tel" class="text phoneNumber" name="tel" placeholder="Phone number" required>
<input type=submit class="submit appended" value=submit>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
//check if form validation passed
if ($(".phoneNumber") == true) {
    //if passed, trigger mixpanel event
}
});
```

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/yjpe0mmc/)

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/yairEO/validator

Comment: you should not use click here - you can submit a form by hitting enter - without clicking the button, it is better to use the submit event of the form: $('form.contact').on('submit',function() {... your validation code here });

Comment: A none valid `form` woulldn't be submited and so won't firing `submit` event. Like @axel.michel said, you should bind `submit` event to the `form` instead, this will solve your problem btw  http://jsfiddle.net/yjpe0mmc/1/

Comment: Based on this update, how can check if the html input validation has passed and is valid?http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/yjpe0mmc/2/

Comment: @Matt If you are using a plugin, post reference in question itself! Otherwise, you question regarding last jsfiddle doesn't make sense because an invalid `form` won't trigger `submit` event

Comment: I'm not using a plugin, nor should I have to in order to check if the html phone required parameter is true or false. I just need to only fire an event if the form input has valid input (full phone number) before firing the mixpanel event from submit.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches you can take .... great comment from @axel.michel. If you use the form's `submit` event instead of the submit button's `click` event, the submit event only triggers **only when the form is valid**:

```
$('form.contact').on('submit', function(e) {
    //FORM IS VALID 
    //stop default form submission so you can do stuff
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff
    //submit form if desired
    this.submit();
});
```

```js
$('form.contact').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( $('.phoneNumber')[0].checkValidity() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class=contact method=get action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form">
<input type="tel" class="text phoneNumber" name="tel" placeholder="Phone number" required>
  
<input type=submit class="submit appended" value=submit>
</div>
```

**The second approach**, if all you want is a way to check that the input element is valid is to add a button for doing that:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $('.phoneNumber')[0].checkValidity() );
});
```

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $('.phoneNumber')[0].checkValidity() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class=contact method=get action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form">
<input type="tel" class="text phoneNumber" name="tel" placeholder="Phone number" required>
<button type="button" class="button">Check Validity</button>  
<input type=submit class="submit appended" value=submit>
</div>
```